# How to hash the security questions in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my data schema for user, I have

```
  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "password_digest"
  end
```

To hash the password we have ' t.string "password_digest"', but what if I want to add security question to users?
Is there any default function for hash the answer for security question?

Comment: are you using a particular gem to provide auth? for example, devise has this module to provide the security questions feature https://github.com/phatworx/devise_security_extension

Answer (score 2):

If your code is working now, then you presumably have [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html) in your model.

This, by default, adds a `password` accessor to your model, and hashes the value into a column called `password_digest`.

You can change the column/attribute name by passing the name as the first argument to `has_secure_password`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_secure_password
  has_secure_password(:security_question_1)
  has_secure_password(:security_question_2)

  ...
```

This will automatically hash `user.security_question_1 = "..."` to a column called `security_question_1_digest`.

Keep in mind:

- this method is tailored for storing short user-generated *passwords*, using BCrypt, which means it has a maximum length of 72 characters.
- this method also adds a `validates_confirmation_of` validator to your model. You can suppress this by passing `validations: false`.

Comment: Which begs the question, shouldn't this method be renamed to or aliased to `has_secure_field` ?

Comment: @lacostenycoder No, it's for passwords. Security questions/answers are really just secondary passwords.